# Is there a difference between \textit and \itshape?

Tags: fonts, best-practices, italic

I have only ever used `\textit` (and `\emph` for emphasized text), but have noticed that in some TeX examples, `\itshape` is used instead of `\textit`. Is there a difference between `\textit` and `\itshape`? If so, what is that difference?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`\itshape` is a switch:

```
Not italic {\itshape Italic} Not italic
```

`\textit` takes an argument:

```
Not italic \textit{Italic} Not italic
```

Many people seem to like `\itshape{...}`, which is wrong (but doesn't give an error since the braces are interpreted as grouping delimiters here).
`\itshape` doesn't automatically insert italic correction, whereas `\textit` does, so inside a paragraph, `\textit` is usually better. On the other hand, sometimes the switch commands are more handy if you already have grouping (e.g., with braces or environments):

```
\begin{table}
  \itshape
  Everything inside this table is italic
\end{table}
```

Comment: So would `\itshape` be best reserved for fully italicized paragraphs (where there is no need for additional spacing at the end of the paragraph)?

Comment: @quidbear, I would pretty much _always_ use `\textit` (actually `\emph`), and only reserve `\itshape` for defining new commands and environments.

Answer (score 39):

- `\itshape` is a *declaration*. It affects the following text. That's why it's often used for larger amounts of text or within a group. In contrast, `\textit` affects only its argument.
- `\textit` provides *italic correction*, `\itshape` does not. This means, that immediately after an italic text made by `\textit` there's a little more space before the following text, compared with `\itshape`. A reason for the correction is, that because of the slanting the spacing could be too narrow, visually. It depends on the font.
- `\textit` works in math mode, `\itshape` doesn't work in math mode.

Here's code for `\textit`, from latex.ltx:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textit}{\itshape}

\def \DeclareTextFontCommand #1#2{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand#1[1]{%
    \ifmmode
      \nfss@text{#2##1}%
    \else
      \hmode@bgroup
       \text@command{##1}%
       #2\check@icl ##1\check@icr
       \expandafter
      \egroup
    \fi
                       }%
}
```

As you can see, `\textit` uses `\itshape` but does more regarding math mode and italic correction.

Answer (score 10):

`\itshape` and others like it (`bfseries`) are modal commands which don't take arguments.  They change all succeeding text to that font shape/weight etc.  `\textit` (and `textbf`) is a macro that takes an argument.