# Why Different Commands for Seemingly Similar Tasks?

Tags: fonts, formatting, macros

Take a look at the following list:

- `\textit`, `\it`, `\emph`, `\itshape`, `\mathit`
- `\textbf`, `\bf`, `\bfseries`, `\mathbf`
- ...

One might say, for instance, that:

- `\mathbf` and `\mathit` are for math mode, while the others are for normal mode.

Or

- `\bf` and `\it` are for plain TeX and obsolete, while the others are for LaTeX.

However, my real question is: What was the need to redefine a command? Couldn't the normal mode commands be carried over to the math mode, or plain TeX commands be carried over to  LaTeX?

PS: Perhaps there are other differences which I don't know. Please mention them in your answer, too.

Comment: See also [this related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7669/1235).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

- `\bf` and `\it` load single fonts and they do not nest; writing `\bf\it` does not give you bold italic.
- `\bfseries` and `\itshape` select font axes in LaTeX. You can use them together to select bold italic, for example.
- `\textbf` and `\textit` are the command forms of the above, with the added feature of inserting italic correction automatically.
- `\emph` is the semantic command for giving *emphasis* to text. (LaTeX lacks an analogy for HTML's `<strong>`.) This is the reason that `\bf` and `\it` are not recommended as names for font-switching, and why the LaTeX forms are longer to type—because they're not semantic, they lack meaning in a text; all they say is ‘select a font’ but whether that's for added meaning or just decoration is unknown.
- `\mathbf` and `\mathit` load fonts for use in maths, which might be the same fonts as used for `\textbf` and `\textit` but not necessarily. Note that combining font shapes doesn't make much sense in maths, so like `\bf` and `\it` these commands do not act orthogonally: one will cancel out the other.

Comment: Just to add: If you want to put *emphasis* on something use the `\emph` macro, not `\textit` even when the result seems identical. One difference is that `\emph` nests properly: e.g. `\emph{This \emph{text} is important}` will make `text` again different so that it sticks out. Also, depending on the style, `\emph` could be coloring the text for an online PDF but make it bold for a large-print copy for the visual impaired.

Comment: One could define, say, `\bf` so that `\it` is redefined inside of it. I'm not sure if that was part of the question ("…or plain TeX commands be carried over to LaTeX?")

Comment: +1. Great answer. Using the keywords in you answer, I found [what’s wrong with \bf, \it, etc.?](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=2letterfontcmd). Also, I found [this page on italic correction](http://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/LTXERR.HTM). It specially gives an example where LaTeX commands do not provide propoer italic correction.

Comment: The last point could be misunderstood: `\mathbf` and `\mathit` load (similar to `\bf` and `\if`) specific fonts. You can't combine them like `\textbf` and `\textit`. `\mathbf{\mathit{a}}` will not give a bold italic "a" but an italic "a" (the inner command wins).

Comment: I just ran into this issue: `\mathbf` does not make Greek letters bold (details omitted). More info is available in [Setting bold Greek letters in LaTeX](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=boldgreek).

Answer (score 3):

Two more differences between `\mathit{}` and `\textit{}` are:

1. `\textit{}` is allowed in both math and regular environment but `\mathit{}` is allowed only in math environment;
2. The `\textit` command provides a regular environment even if it is wrapped by a math environment. Consequently: `$\textit{text1^{text2}}$` gives an error, but `$\mathit{text1^{text2}}$` is valid. Moreover, the output of `$\textit{a b}$` contains a space between a and b, but the output of `$\mathit{a b}$` does not.