# What is the difference between \em and \emph?

Tags: emphasis

What is the difference between `\emph{...}` and `{\em ...}`?

When to use each of them?

Comment: Take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11199/86 as well.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`\emph` is like e.g. `\textit` a command with an argument. `\em` is the "switch" variant, comparable to `\itshape`. `\em` is not an outdated TeX or LaTeX2.09 command but a real LaTeX2e command. Actually `\emph` is defined through `em`:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\em}
```

`\em` is useful for long texts (`\emph` e.g. doesn't allow the argument to contain a `\par`). The commands differ (like the `\textit`/`\itshape`) in their handling of the italic correction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

abc\emph{lll}lll  \textit{lll}llll

abc{\em lll}lll  {\itshape lll}llll

abc{\em lll\/}lll

%\emph{abc\par bc} error

{\em abc\par bc}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the above code sample]

Comment: By the way the `\/` sequence is not a normal spacing command but the so-called `italics correction', see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459454/latex-sequence

Comment: I am thoroughly confused as to what is the importance of "e.g." here.

Answer (score 10):

*l2tabu* (a guide to obsolete commands and packages, available in [English](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) and, more up-to-date, in [German](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/german/l2tabu.pdf)) comments on `\em` as follows:

> May be useful when defining macros. In continuous text `\emph{...}` should be preferred to `\em`.

(Table 1, p. 8 [en] / 10 [de])

Answer (score 9):

`\emph` is a LaTeX2e command and `\em` is a LaTeX 2.09 declaration, see e.g. http://www.public.asu.edu/~rjansen/latexdoc/emph.html . Since you're probably using LaTeX2e you should use `\emph`.

- `\emph` is a command and is used like `\emph{text}`.
- `\em` is a declaration and is used like `\em text` or `{\em text}`.

Their differences may be demonstrated by the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

some \em text% Works as intended

some {\em text}% Works as intended

some \em{text}% Does not work as intended, "text" is not emphasized

some \emph{text}% Works as intended

some \emph text% Does not work as intended, only "t" of "text" is emphasized

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\em{text}` will emphasize "text".  But it won't work as intended because it will emphasize everything afterward as well.

Answer (score 2):

To get a more indepth description see [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts) and [texfaq](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2letterfontcmd). Let me present what is there in a condensed form, because I think the origin of misusing `\em` and `\emph` comes from not knowing how they help specifying a font.

### Font Specification Now

Specification of a font works by choosing a series, a shape, a family and a size. You can choose from 3 series, 4 shapes and 3 families: One of

- `\bfseries,\mdseries,\lfseries` switches to the series,
- `\upshape,\itshape,\slshape,\scshape` switches to the shape,
- `\rmfamily,\sffamily,\ttfamily` switches to the family.

Enclosing the text in braces makes it to a TeX group, thus restores the previous series/shape/family at closing brace. If you choose a slanted or italic shape you have to apply an italic correction (`\/`). You can use the non-switch version of these: Take the first two letters and appent "text", this is the name of an ordinary command that works as expected i.e. either acts on a single char or on a text enclosed in braces.

### Font Specification Then

Before LaTeX2e there were only switch like statements like `\bf,\tt,\em`. They modified the text as long as no other was encountered. This is why `\em{abc}de` gives "*abcde*": `{abc}` is just a group, since no different switch is ancountered `\em` does not stop working at the closing brace. `\it I\bf like \it\bf fresh air` gives "*I* **like fresh air**".

### emph & em

Well... sorry for the overhead. `\em` is different in that it not really is a switch to italics like `\it/\itshape`. It just switches from upright/small-capitals to italics or from italics/slanted to upright when it is encountered (switches the shape) and leaves the family and series untouched. Thus the definition of `\emph` should be losely equivalent to `\def\emph#1{\/{\em#1}\/}`. Which works as expected:
`{\upshape a\emph{b\emph{c\emph{d}e}f}g}` yields "a *b* c *d* e *f* g" (without the spaces of course). The Implemetation in LaTeX2e is of course different, they use `\DeclareTextFontComand{\emph}{\em}` which does a similar thing but also checks for mathmode.

The most imporatant thing is the Implementation of `\em` in LaTeX2e which is indeed such that the behaviour as said above: `{\scshape Aha \em Aha \em Aha}` yields "AHA *Aha* Aha" where the AHA is in small capitals (the scshape ist *not*  restored after the 2nd `\em`).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, `em` is the `TeX` command and `emph` is its `LaTeX` equivalent. Therefore, you should use the `emph` when using `LaTeX`.

Comment: \em is a plain tex command, _not_ something defined by the engine.  it requires you to write your own italic correction commands, which \emph works out for you.

Comment: Neither `\em` nor `\emph` are defined in plain.tex.