# Change order in acronym

Tags: acronyms

I am using `\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}` to use acronyms in my thesis
But I want to get

[image]

instead of

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
Analisis de Componentes Principales (\em{\ac{PCA}}). \ac {PCA}.

\section{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{PCA}{Principal Component Analysis}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to redefine the internal command that typesets the first appearance of an acronym, `\@acf`. This will change *all* first appearances of acronyms, though. If you only want it for the one instance it's easier just to place `\acs` and `\acl` manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@acf}[1]{%
  \ifAC@footnote
    \acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}}%
    \footnote{\AC@placelabel{#1}\hskip\z@\AC@acl{#1}{}}%
  \else
    \acffont{%
      \acfsfont{\acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}}}% I removed the brackets and switched this line ...
      \nolinebreak[3] %
      \AC@placelabel{#1}\hskip\z@\AC@acl{#1}% ... with this one
    }%
  \fi
  \ifAC@starred\else\AC@logged{#1}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
Analisis de Componentes Principales (\emph{\ac{PCA}}). \ac {PCA}.

\section{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{PCA}{Principal Component Analysis}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I also replaced `\em` with `\emph`, see “[What is the difference between `\em` and `\emph`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25911/what-is-the-difference-between-em-and-emph)” for a discussion of the differences.