# Change color of sections in resume class

Tags: sectioning, color, cv, resume

I would like to change the color of the name on top and the titles of the `rSection` in "light gray". How can I do that?

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% USED PACKAGES
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum,textcomp}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\name{firstName Name}% Your name
\address{Adress \\ City, country} % Your address
\address{(+49)~$\cdot$~(0)1111~$\cdot$~11111111 \\ name@name.com} % Your phone number and email

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PERSONAL DATA
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Personal Data}

{\bf Born in City, Country.} \hfill {\em Date, year}

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you point us to the class file you are using.

Answer (score 2):

1. A simple way would be to just redefine the `rSection` environment:

   ```
   \renewenvironment{rSection}[1]{
   \sectionskip
   \textcolor{lightgray}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
   \sectionlineskip
   \hrule
   \begin{list}{}{
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
   }
   \item[]
   }{
   \end{list}
   }
   ```

   which yields:

   [image]
2. One downside of the above is that if the `resume.cls` file makes changes to the `rSection` environment you will not see them. An alternative is to redefine the `\MakeUppercase` macro when we are *within* the `rSection` environment.

   ```
   \let\OrigRSection\rSection
   \let\OrigEndRSection\endrSection
   \let\OrigMakeUppercase\MakeUppercase

   \renewenvironment{rSection}[1]{
       \renewcommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{\textcolor{lightgray}{\OrigMakeUppercase{##1}}}%
       \OrigRSection{#1}%
   }{%
       \OrigEndRSection%
   }
   ```

### Notes:

- I downloaded `resume.cls` from https://github.com/treyhunner/resume/blob/master/resume.cls. Not sure if this is the correct one though.
- I have replaced `\bf` with `\bfseries`, and `\em` with `\emph{}`. Please see [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc), and [What is the difference between \em and \emph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25911/what-is-the-difference-between-em-and-emph).

---

### Code: Redefine `rSection` environment

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% USED PACKAGES
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum,textcomp}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\renewenvironment{rSection}[1]{
\sectionskip
\textcolor{lightgray}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\sectionlineskip
\hrule
\begin{list}{}{
\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
}
\item[]
}{
\end{list}
}





\name{firstName Name}% Your name
\address{Address \\ City, country} % Your address
\address{(+49)~$\cdot$~(0)1111~$\cdot$~11111111 \\ name@name.com} % Your phone number and email


\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PERSONAL DATA
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Personal Data}

{\bfseries Born in City, Country.} \hfill {\emph{Date, year}}

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Redefine `\MakeUppercase` *within* `rSection`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% USED PACKAGES
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum,textcomp}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\let\OrigRSection\rSection
\let\OrigEndRSection\endrSection
\let\OrigMakeUppercase\MakeUppercase

\renewenvironment{rSection}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{\textcolor{lightgray}{\OrigMakeUppercase{##1}}}%
    \OrigRSection{#1}%
}{%
    \OrigEndRSection%
}



\name{firstName Name}% Your name
\address{Address \\ City, country} % Your address
\address{(+49)~$\cdot$~(0)1111~$\cdot$~11111111 \\ name@name.com} % Your phone number and email


\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PERSONAL DATA
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Personal Data}

{\bfseries Born in City, Country.} \hfill {\emph{Date, year}}

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```