# tex4ht: possible conflict between \emph and \xymatrix

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook, xymatrix

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\emph{
  Test
  \[
    \xymatrix@C-20pt{
      {\mathbf R} f_*\big[{\mathbf L} f^*A\otimes^{\mathbf L} f^\times{\mathcal O}_Y^{}\big]\ar[dr]_-{{\mathbf R} f_*\chi}\ar[rr]^-{p_{A,f^\times{\mathcal O}_Y^{}}^{-1}}& & A  \otimes_{}^{\mathbf L}{\mathbf R} f_*f^\times {\mathcal O}_Y^{} \ar[rr]^-{{\mathrm{id}}\otimes\varepsilon} &&  A\otimes^{\mathbf L}_{}{\mathcal O}_Y^{}\ar@{=}[dl]\\
      & {\mathbf R} f_*f^\times A\ar[rr]_-\varepsilon && A &
    }
  \]
  Test
}
\end{document}
```

I compile it with `tex4ebook`, getting errors as follows:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   15   Double superscript.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   15   Double superscript.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   15   Double superscript.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   15   Double superscript.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   15   Double superscript.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   15   Double superscript.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   15   Double superscript.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   15   Double superscript.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   15   Double superscript.
```

which is pretty incomprehensible. There is no error if I put the `\[` ... `\]` part outside `\emph`. No error for `pdflatex`. I expect explications for this.

Comment: this cannot work. or maybe could, but the amount of hacks needed to support that would be too high. it is better to not mix inline markup and things that introduce paragraphs.

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks. You mean, use `\emph` only for "in line" purposes? How to italicize blocks properly?

Comment: @Yai0Phah use `\itshape`, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258394/make-block-of-text-italicized.

Comment: @Yai0Phah yes, I would use it only for the "in line" purposes. for something what can contain multiple paragraphs, I would use a custom environment. They are much simpler to support in HTML conversion.