# Why is the bibliography so weird?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texmaker

I am using Texmaker for my paper and I encounter a problem here and hope somebody can help me.

[image: Latex glossary]

As you can see here, the titles are some in Italics and some are not. What cause this anyway? I don't use cite btw, only footnote.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[Monopolkommision (1988)]{monopol1988} Monopolkommision (1988): \em{Siebentes Hauptgutachten der Monopolkommission 1986/1987}, In: Deutscher Bundestag Online, 19.07.1988 (http://dipbt.bundestag.de/doc/btd/11/026/1102677.pdf vom 16.08.2016).
\bibitem[Monopolkommision (1992)]{monopol1992} Monopolkommision (1992): \em{Neuntes Hauptgutachten der Monopolkommission 1990/1991} (http://dipbt.bundestag.de/doc/btd/12/030/1203031.pdf vom 16.08.2016).
\bibitem[Monopolkommision (2016)]{monopol2016} Monopolkommision (2016): \em{Wettbewerb 2016: Einundzwanzigstes Hauptgutachten der Monopolkommission gemäß § 44 Abs. 1 Satz 1 GWB} (http://www.monopolkommission.de/index.php/de/gutachten/hauptgutachten/liste-hauptgutachten vom 21.09.2016).

\end{thebibliography}
```

what is wrong here? these are the packages i used.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,german , a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=45mm,
 right=15mm,
 top=25mm,
 bottom=15mm,
 } 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\onehalfspacing
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\nocite{*}
```

I did have some renewcommand, but I think this is not the cause.

```
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literaturen}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhalt}
%\renewcommand{\acronymname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textbf{Abbildung}}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\renewcommand\listtablename{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt{10}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\makeatother
```

I think I post in the wrong website since nobody answer me on Stackoverflow. Anyway thank you for the help.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) that is not a glossary, that is a bibliography. Note that `\em` is a switch, i.e. it does not take any arguments, so after `\em{...}` the font is still `\em`. Use `\emph` instead

Comment: BTW: next time please provide a full minimal example in one go, not just a preamble and a few other pieces. That will make it a lot more likely that you will get help

Comment: You have to use it either this way: `{\em emphasized text}` or this way: `\emph{emphasized text}`.

Comment: @daleif, thank you for your reply. And sorry I don't understand what is preamble. I have to read more about Latex. I just start using Latex few weeks ago, so I still don't pretty used to it yet.

Comment: @gernot, Thank you, It is working now... I am only know about \em{} I just copy paste and trying what I can find in websites... Can you guys give me an idea, where I can learn more about latex. Best sources and good written one. Since English is not my mother tongue.... thank you.

Comment: @user3392555 What *is* your mother tongue?

Comment: If you are a new user, you should read a latex introduction. Nicola Talbot has written a nice one,   http://www.dickimaw-books.com/people/nicola-talbot.html, there are many others and probably also in your native tongue. But there are also bad introductions and videos out there. In the introductions you'll learn about the various terminologies. In this case the **preamble ** is the area of your document that comes before `\begin{document} `, it is used to configure your document

Comment: Why do you load `biblatex` (twice!) if you then use the manual `thebibliography`? Check http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html as well as http://biblatex.dominik-wassenhoven.de/download/DTK-2_2008-biblatex-Teil1.pdf for help on how to really use `biblatex`; also http://www.komascript.de/latexvorlage. See also [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864).

Comment: @gernot sorry for the delay, I just had my last exam and wrapping up my paper. Indonesian is my mother tongue. I am in German right now, that why my paper in german.

Comment: @daleif, moewe thank you for the resources, it will help my next paper absolutely... I just saw it, after you pointed it out. It was mistake put it twice. Like I said, I just copy paste whatever I found in internet. I had no base on Latex.

Answer (score 0):

@Gernot just pointed out, the mistake is not on the bibliography rather than emphasis.

For more info

[What is the difference between \em and \emph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25911/what-is-the-difference-between-em-and-emph)