# Use Geometry Package for custom page margin settings after header

Tags: header-footer, margins

I want to use geometry package for custom page margin setting after the header. Currently my documents looks like

[image]

I want to use `geometry` package to expand `EDUCATION` section so it should look like as follows

[image]

I've generated the above image using following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements
\pagenumbering{gobble} 
\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} 

\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{394456}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{5A7294}
\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip}
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section

% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}



\begin{document}


\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf University} \hfill {\em Start - End} 
\\ Degree\hfill { Overall CGPA: 4}

\end{rSection}

\end{document
```

Now if I don't use the `geometry` package my code for the first image would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements
\pagenumbering{gobble} 


\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{394456}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{5A7294}
\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip}
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section

% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [rectangle, fill=darkgray, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=3cm] (box) at (current page.north){};


\node [text=white,font=\fontsize{45pt}{65pt}\bfseries\sffamily,anchor=north
west] (name) at ([xshift=2em,yshift=-2em]box.north west) {%
John Doe
};
\node [text=blue!20,font=\fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\bfseries\sffamily,anchor=north
west] (name) at ([xshift=0.5ex]name.south west) {%
Job title
};

\node[anchor=east] at ([xshift=-2em]box.east)
{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf University} \hfill {\em Start - End} 
\\ Degree\hfill { Overall CGPA: 4}

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

How can I get header from first image and education section with custom margin settings using geometry package as demonstrated in second image?

I need to use margin settings only for the part after my header.

Comment: why do you want to use geometry here? your page heading and page size isn't changing, you have just defined `rSection` to be a list so aren't you just asking about the list margins within the existing page?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes I just want to change margins for `rSection` you can provide a method if you know of that would work other than using `geometry`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle by tweaking `\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}` margins would only change for items in the list, not for the horizontal line above those items and the section heading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include the `tikzpicture` after `\begin{document}` and increase the `top` margin to leave enough space (the Ti*k*Z picture takes no space because it uses the `overlay` option—it appears as a zero-size box for TeX at the point where it occurs).

Use `\newcommand` rather than `\def` and `\textbf` rather than `\bf`. `\emph` is easier to use than `\em` in general because it [automatically provides italic correction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25918/73317).

I removed possible spurious spaces and added `\par\nopagebreak` after your section title to ensure the following `\medskip` isn't a legal breakpoint.

The font sizes your code requests are not available unless you change your font setup. I added `\usepackage{lmodern}`, this makes them available. I also replaced `Start - End` with `Start -- End` (em dash: longer than a hyphen).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=3cm,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry}

\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{394456}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{5A7294}
\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\newcommand{\sectionlineskip}{\medskip}
\newcommand{\sectionskip}{\medskip}

% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{% 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1}% Section title
  \par\nopagebreak
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{% List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }%
  \item[]
}{%
  \end{list}
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[rectangle, fill=darkgray, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth,
      minimum height=3cm] (box) at (current page.north) {};

\node[text=white,font=\fontsize{45pt}{65pt}\bfseries\sffamily,
      anchor=north west] (name) at ([xshift=2em,yshift=-2em]box.north west)
  {John Doe};

\node[text=blue!20, font=\fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\bfseries\sffamily,
      anchor=north west] (name) at ([xshift=0.5ex]name.south west)
  {Job title};

\node[anchor=east] at ([xshift=-2em]box.east)
  {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{rSection}{Education}
\textbf{University}\hfill \emph{Start -- End}\\
Degree\hfill Overall CGPA: 4
\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

[image]