# How to change the appearance of subsections, subsubsections, etc. in an AMS Article?

Tags: formatting, titlesec, amsart

Suppose I have the following document:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\subsection{Subsection}
Content.

\end{document}
```

How can I modify the code so that the subsection heading is italic instead of bold? I tried to use the `titlesec` package, but I don't think it is compatible with the AMS document classes:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\subsection}{\it}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Subsection}
Content.

\end{document}
```

It works with the Article document class, but it produces errors in an AMS Article.

Edit: I would also like a space between the subsection title and the content, as in the typical Article document class.

Comment: It really is easiest to present a Minimum Working Example that illustrates your problem; this is especially true when you are pulling in code from another question (that itself refers to yet another question)...

Comment: Note that `\it` is somewhat deprecated ... better to use `\itshape`.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11200/47522.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @cslstr: I've posted a related question, about how to italicize the heading and optional title of a theorem. I'd appreciate it if you'd take a look at it. Your answers are very good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\subsection` is defined in `amsart.cls` as:

```
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
```

This definition can be patched to redefine the font with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\itshape}{}{}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Subsection}
Content.

\end{document}
```

This will give the `subsection` style as:

[image]

### Edit: Remove in-line heading

The in-line heading is caused by the `-.5em` distance that is given for separation.  A negative number is interpreted as "horizontal distance to skip".  To have the section start on the next line (and the number interpreted as "vertical distance to skip"), this must be a positive number.  This can be accomplished by adding:

```
\patchcmd{\subsection}{-.5em}{.5em}{}{}
```

The full example (with a bit more text) becomes:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for extra text
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\itshape}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{-.5em}{.5em}{}{}


\begin{document}

\subsection{Subsection}
Content. \lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: newparagraph]

Comment: Cool, thanks. One more thing: How can I make a space between the subsection title and the content, as in the regular Article document class?

Comment: see update. :-)

Comment: Damn. That was fast. :)