# Why may a \medskip have different height between two paragraphs out of several?

Tags: vertical-spacing

I had to separate half a dozen paragraphs vertically and added `\medskip` between each of them. Strangely, there is an extra distance between only two of them. The top and bottom skips are correct, but the one in the middle is about 2x times taller. Can this be avoided?

[image]

Comment: We'll need to see your code to clarify what you've done and suggest any solutions.

Comment: the code you have not shown will be allowing twice the space at that point. If you show an example that produces that image someone could debug it.

Comment: My guess is you have a blank line at the wide skip. Did you end the paragraph with \\? What do I get if I win the guessing game?

Comment: Does the paragraph preceding the wider space end with the last line at the right margin?  If so, this answer explains what's happening, although it was answering a somewhat different question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297502  In order to provide a specific answer, we need to see your code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that which @barbara beeton suggested: the last line ended at the margin. Rephrasing the paragraph allowed me to spill it into another line, and the height of the subsequent `\medskip` became equal with the rest.