# Is there something similar to \itshape but for \emph text?

Tags: italic, emphasis

**Edit: this question is misinformed and the chosen answer answers a different question altogether.**

`\emph` produces slightly better italicized text for certain symbols, e.g., punctuation. Right now, I use `\itshape` to force a style on a block of text.

```
\lstdefinelanguage{Scheme}{
  % basewidth=0.5em,
  sensitive=true,
  basicstyle=\normalsize\rmfamily,
  commentstyle=\itshape\rmfamily\color[rgb]{.9, .5,.1},
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\sffamily\color[rgb]{0,.3,.7},
  morecomment=[l]{;},
  frameshape={RYR}{Y}{Y}{RYR},
  identifierstyle=\emph\rmfamily,
  keywords={define, lambda, let, cond, else},
  escapeinside={(*;}{;*)},
  columns=fullflexible
}
```

The problem is that I want to use `\emph` for "comments" in my listing and not just `\itshape`. Is there something similar that I can use (because I'd rather not have to escape and unescape every instance where I want to use `\emph`)?

Edit: it seems that `\em` is what I'm looking for, but my problem is more involved than that. The problem is that the `identifierstyle` doesn't italicize question marks using the above listing. See the image and code listing below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{listings, skins, breakable}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{0.9, 0.5, 0.1}
\lstdefinelanguage{Scheme}{
  % basewidth=0.5em,
  sensitive=true,
  basicstyle=\normalsize\rmfamily,
  commentstyle=\itshape\rmfamily\color[rgb]{.9, .5,.1},
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\sffamily\color[rgb]{0,.3,.7},
  morecomment=[l]{;},
  frameshape={RYR}{Y}{Y}{RYR},
  identifierstyle=\em\rmfamily,
  keywords={define, lambda, let, cond, else},
  escapeinside={(*;}{;*)},
  columns=fullflexible
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Scheme]
;; rember(*;\textcolor{myorange}{\textrm{:}};*) (*;\textcolor{myorange}{\textsf{Atom}};*) (*;\textcolor{myorange}{\textsf{[ListOf Atom]}};*) (*;\textcolor{myorange}{$\to$};*) (*;\textcolor{myorange}{\textsf{Atom}};*)
;;   Comment here...
(define rember
  ((*;$\lambda$;*) (a lat)
    (cond
      [(null? lat) (quote ())]
      [else (cond
              [(eqv? (car lat) a) (cdr lat)]
              [else (rember a (cdr lat))])])))
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do check out the postings [What is the difference between `\em` and `\emph`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25911/5001) and [Why Different Commands for Seemingly Similar Tasks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11199/5001)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `\emph` producing “better italicized text”. Can you please explain?

Comment: @egreg I want question marks, in particular, to be italicized. `\textit` does not italicize punctuation, which looks off when working with certain pieces of text. Perhaps it's better to just slightly redefine `\textit`?

Comment: @TheProgrammer Really? Try `\textit{?}` and see.

Comment: @egreg Hm... it seems that my question is more complicated than just using `\em` or `\itshape`. The context is that I'm trying to use a `lstlisting` to show some programming code. I want identifiers to use `\rmstyle` and `\itshape`. The problem is that everything *but* the question marks are italicized. I've updated my question.

Comment: @TheProgrammer Please add a compilable test document to your question which allows us to reproduce the problem. Puzzling your code blocks together does not give italic text.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Good point - sorry about that. It is added in its entirety.

Comment: Your question is misconceived: The choice to print `?` in roman rather than italics is made by the language definition in `lstlisting`, and has nothing to do with font choices. I would look at the docs for lstlisting and if you’re not sure how to change the definition, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listings will print the identifiers in italic, but the `?` is not part of the identifiers.

You can force listings to print it in italic by making it a normal letter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{listings, skins, breakable}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{0.9, 0.5, 0.1}
\lstdefinelanguage{Scheme}{
   basewidth=0.5em,
  sensitive=true,
  basicstyle=\normalsize\rmfamily,
  commentstyle=\itshape\rmfamily\color[rgb]{.9, .5,.1},
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\sffamily\color[rgb]{0,.3,.7},
  morecomment=[l]{;},
  frameshape={RYR}{Y}{Y}{RYR},
  identifierstyle=\itshape\rmfamily,
  alsoletter={?},
  keywords={define, lambda, let, cond, else},
  escapeinside={(*;}{;*)},
  columns=fullflexible
}
\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[language=Scheme]
;; rember(*;\textcolor{myorange}{\textrm{:}};*) (*;\textcolor{myorange}{\textsf{Atom}};*) (*;\textcolor{myorange}{\textsf{[ListOf Atom]}};*) (*;\textcolor{myorange}{$\to$};*) (*;\textcolor{myorange}{\textsf{Atom}};*)
;;   Comment here...
(define rember
  ((*;$\lambda$;*) (a lat)
    (cond
      [(null? lat) (quote ())]
      [else (cond
              [(eqv? (car lat) a) (cdr lat)]
              [else (rember a (cdr lat))])])))
\end{lstlisting}

\itshape null?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My only comment is that while this solves the problem, the question itself is perhaps misinformed and it makes sense for this answer to be attached to a new question which actually asks the correct question.

Comment: @DonHosek I 100% agree that the question is misinformed. Should I create a new question, then post an answer, or should I let sam answer it? Not really sure what to do in this situation.

Comment: @TheProgrammer That's why your questions should always have a minimal working example which allow users to reproduce your problem. Disconnected code fragments are never a good idea.

Comment: @TheProgrammer I don't think a new question would be very useful, I'm pretty sure we already have some duplicate. Search the site for `alsoletter`.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you redefine `\emph{}`,  by default  it uses `\em` internally, that uses `\itshape` internally, so both commands should produce exactly the same italics:

**`\emph` definition:**

`\ifmmode \nfss@text {`**`\em`** `#1}\else \hmode@bgroup \text@command {#1}\em \check@icl #1\check@icr \expandafter \egroup \fi`

**`\em` definition:**

`\@nomath \em \ifx \emfontdeclare@clist \@empty \ifdim \fontdimen \@ne \font >\z@ \eminnershape \else` **`\itshape`** `\fi \else \edef \em@currfont {\csname \curr@fontshape /\f@size \endcsname }\expandafter \do@emfont@update \emfontdeclare@clist \do@emfont@update \fi`

The  main  difference, is that `\emph`, like `\textit`, corrects the space after the italics, while with `\itshape` or `\em` is your work make the so called "italic correction". That is, `\emph{l}l` or  `\textit{l}l` will have some extra spacing between the two letters, compared with  `{\em l}l` or `{\itshape l}l`, that are too close, and then is your work type `{\em l\/}l` or `{\itshape l\/}l` to avoid that.

Well, another important difference is that `\emph` or `\em` means "emphasis", not "italics", and therefore `{\em l{\em l}l}` will produce

[image: mwe]

while `{\itshape l{\itshape l}l}` will produce only italics, because it have sense emphasize a text in italics, but not italicize it again.

Therefore, is OK redefine `\emph` or better `\em`  only if you  to make emphasis with some that is not italics (e.g., bold or slant font) or return main font in nested emphasis, but you should avoid redefine `\textit` or`\itshape` because then the meaning of  the commands are misleading and will produce unexpected results in any package using these commands.

As Mico warns in the comment, still one more difference is the math mode, fact that you can already suspect trying to decipher above the cryptic definitions, so you can type `$\emph{x}$` or `$\textit{x}$`, but not `${\em x}$` nor `${\itshape x}}$`.

Comment: +1. Another difference between `\emph` and `\em` is that the former can be used while in mode, whereas the latter can not. (This difference also applies to `\textit` vs `\itshape`, `\textsc` vs `\scshape`, and so on.) Hence, `$\emph{l}$` is ok, whereas `${\em l}l$` can not. Of course, nobody actually recommends writing `${\em l}l$`...

Comment: @Mico Very true. Added to the answer.

Comment: @Mico The fact that `\emph` can be used in math mode is purely coincidental.

Comment: @egreg - Agreed.

Comment: @egreg or @Mico Can you explain?  Why is coincidental with `\emph` but not in `\textit`, for instance? Both commands have a   `\nfss@text{...}`,  that as far I see, is  like put `\em` or `\itshape` in a `\mbox`, so?

Comment: @Fran You do want to be able to use `\textit` or similar commands in math (think to `cases`, for instance), but `\emph` doesn't really make much sense in this context.

Comment: @egreg Oh, I understand, in the semantic  sense... I thought you refer to some kind of code serendipity  in  `\emph` definition, haha. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The corresponding switch for `\emph` is `\em`.

So instead of `\itshape` you can use `\em`.