# How can I use multiple declarations (\textbf, \emph) in listings' emphstyle?

Tags: listings, emphasis

How do I provide multiple emphstyles with the listings package?

```
\begin{lstlisting}[emph={if,for},emphstyle={\textbf\emph}]
if something
end if
\end{lstlisting}
```

Both styles above (`\emph` and `\textbf`} don't get applied. If I use only one style, it works.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you want it to be italic and boldshape. By using `\itshape` and `\bfseries` instead it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[emph={if,for},emphstyle={\bfseries\itshape}]
if something
end if
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wonder from where they expect you to learn that.

Comment: @Salil: Experience `:)` Perhaps this is a start: [Is there a difference between \textit and \itshape?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/is-there-a-difference-between-textit-and-itshape) The motivation here is that `\textbf`, `\textit` and `\textsf` are *local macros* that take arguments, while `\bfseries`, `\itshape` and `\sffamily` are *switches*.