# How can I define multiple identifier classes and styles in listings?

Tags: listings, color

I'm trying to add different styles (color, etc.) to different groups of words in the `listings` package. Note that my question is different from [How can I use multiple declarations (\textbf, \emph) in listings' emphstyle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35441/how-can-i-use-multiple-declarations-textbf-emph-in-listings-emphstyle).

Let me show you some code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document} 
...
\begin{lstlisting}
    {
        "id": {integer},
        "login": {string},
        "password": {string},
        "name": {string},
        "picture": {
            File Resource
        }
    }    
    ...       
    PUT /files/{file_id}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I use the `\lstset` command to define the following:

```
...
    emph={  % HTTP Request
        GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
    },
    emphstyle={\color{green}},
...
```

but I would like to add more words with a different style (color, etc.), like so

```
...
    emph2={  % Variable Types
        integer,string,blob,datetime
    },
    emphstyle2={\color{darkBlue}},
...
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks for this question! It actually led me to solve a problem I was having with the formatting of my listings :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're halfway there. The `listings` manual (p.31 in v1.5b) tells you that multiple classes of identifiers and associated styles can be defined by using

```
\emph=[<number>]{<identifier list>}
\emphstyle=[<number>]{<identifier style>}
```

where `<number>` is some integer of your choice that gets associated with the class of identifiers in question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset%
{%
    emph=[1]%
    {%
        DELETE,
        GET,
        POST,
        PUT,
    },
    emphstyle=[1]{\color{green}},
    %
    emph=[2]% Variable Types
    {% 
        blob,
        datetime,
        integer,
        string,
    },
  emphstyle=[2]{\color{blue}},
}

\begin{document} 
...
\begin{lstlisting}
    {
        "id": {integer},
        "login": {string},
        "password": {string},
        "name": {string},
        "picture": {
            File Resource
        }
    }    
    ...       
    PUT /files/{file_id}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: minutes after the question, I found this in the manual! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Guilherme No problem. And I learned something in the process of posting this answer. Two birds with one stone!

Comment: Great answer! But how to use special characters like '#' as keyword? I try to add an #endif keyword

Answer (score 3):

A supplement to @Jubobs's answer as a reminder for users of `listings v1.6` (maybe also for versions later on, I haven't checked yet).

In `listings v1.6`, the valid syntax for specifying group in `emph` and `keywords` has been changed into

```
emph={[2]...}, emphstyle={[2]...}
keywords={[1]...}, keywordstyle={[1]...}
```

These can be found in the `listings` manual (v1.6, p22).