# Listings Keyword Part of Comment

Tags: listings, comments, keywords

I made a homebrewed language for structured text (because I expected no language like this to be available). Now there is a comment that starts with `/*` and ends with `*/` and a line comment that starts with `//`... but I also need the `/` for division highlighting. Everything works but the comments that start with `/` are not highlighted. What can I do?

I got another question. Is it possible to have two groups of otherkeywords in two different styles? I think I will need this because I have to highlight all numbers in a different color than the keywords `+`, `-`, etc.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163800/21891 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148193/how-can-i-define-multiple-identifier-classes-and-styles-in-listings. Also, be aware that highlighting numbers in a given style is notoriously difficult with `listings`.

Comment: Also, please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.