# Customize Color for lstset morekeywords

Tags: listings, color, python

I have done some extensive searching and have yet to find the answer to changing the color for lstset morekeywords.  I want them to be a different color than my regular keywords.  Here is what I have right now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,lstautogobble}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

% Custom Python Syntax
\lstset
{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{Green},
    keywordstyle=\color{Cerulean},
    frame=single,
    language=python,
    morekeywords={True, False},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=10pt,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize\color{Gray},
    showstringspaces=false,
    stringstyle=\color{Mulberry},
    tabsize=3,
}

% Color Numbers
\lstset
{
    literate=%
    {0}{{{\color{Orange}0}}}1
    {1}{{{\color{Orange}1}}}1
    {2}{{{\color{Orange}2}}}1
    {3}{{{\color{rOrange}3}}}1
    {4}{{{\color{Orange}4}}}1
    {5}{{{\color{Orange}5}}}1
    {6}{{{\color{Orange}6}}}1
    {7}{{{\color{Orange}7}}}1
    {8}{{{\color{Orange}8}}}1
    {9}{{{\color{Orange}9}}}1
}

\begin{document}

    % A basic function that tests if a number is prime
    \lstinputlisting{isPrime.py}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following result[image: Screenshot from my computer]

As you can see on lines 16 and 17 **True** and **False** are the same color as **return** and right next to each other.  I am just wondering if I could just change the color of selected keywords.  For instance changing **True** and **False** to a darker blue or another color entirely.

**Also:** This is less of a concern but is there a better way to change the color of the numbers (not the line numbers, the numbers in the code)? What I have clearly works but I feel like it's a little inefficient.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `morekeywords` merely adds more keywords to the existing list; it won't allow you to give `True` and `False` a distinct style from the existing one. If you want to create additional but separate lists of keywords, each list with a distinct style, you should check out http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148193/how-can-i-define-multiple-identifier-classes-and-styles-in-listings

Comment: Hey Christian, thanks for the hint. I forgot the document class but I have added that now.

Comment: @StephenClark You should also add the code for your listing. If you load the `filecontents` package, you will be able put the contents of `isPrime.py` inside a `\begin{filecontents*}{isPrime.py} ... \end{filecontents*}` environment.

Comment: Also, you're missing a colon at the end of `for val in range(1, num)`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `classoffset` before you define the `morekeywords`. The specifications below say that `True` should be in WildStrawberry and `False` in LimeGreen:

[image]

Here is  hack of your customisation:

```
% Custom Python Syntax
\lstset
{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{Green},
    frame=single,
    language=python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=10pt,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize\color{Gray},
    showstringspaces=false,
    stringstyle=\color{Mulberry},
    otabsize=3,
    % the more interesting/new bits
    classoffset=1,% starting a new class
    morekeywords={True},
    keywordstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    classoffset=2,% starting another class
    morekeywords={False},
    keywordstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    classoffset=0,% restore to default class if more customisations...
}
```

Comment: Using `classoffset` is not very robust, though; it's easy to make mistakes with it. A better alternative, IMO, is to specify the class offset like so: `keywords=[<class-offset>]<style>`.