# Font style in mdframed

Tags: fonts, mdframed

I use the following `mdframed` definition:

```
\newmdenv[
    rightline=false, leftline=true,
    topline=false, bottomline=false,
    innerbottommargin=11pt, innertopmargin=\topskip,
    splittopskip=\topskip,
    skipbelow=\baselineskip, skipabove=\baselineskip,
    innerleftmargin=11pt, innerrightmargin=0,
    linewidth=2,font={\sffamily}
]{MarkedC}
```

to set text in an appendix:

```
\chapter{This is the Appendix}
\begin{MarkedC}
    Lots of text ...
\end{MarkedC}
```

This works as expected: the text is set in `sffamily` (to distinguish it from the rest of the document) with a solid line on the left.

Ideally though, I would prefer the `MarkedC` text to be set in *italics*, rather than in a different font. How can I achieve this?

Comment: replace `\sffamily` by `\itshape`?

Comment: Yes. Post that as an answer :) `\emph` didn't work (obviously) and I didn't know about `\itshape`.

Comment: [`\itshape` is the font switch equivalent to `\textit{}`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/is-there-a-difference-between-textit-and-itshape), like `\em` to `\emph{}` or `\bfseries` to `\textbf{}`.