# aboveglftskip in expex linguistic glosses

Tags: spacing, linguistics, examples, expex

First of all I am not an expert in using LaTeX, I just started a few months back.

I am using MiKTeX with the `expex` package for glossed linguistic examples. 
If we take a look at a glossed example, we see a space above the fourth line which is the free translation (`\glft`):

[image]

To get rid of the vertical spacing above the glft-line, the expex documentation advisies you to use the command "`aboveglftskip=0pt`" in the `\begingl` column.
I used this command in my document, but it still gives me a gloss with spacing before `\glft`.
I am using a weird template with a bunch of stuff in it, but it's likely to the beamer class.
But even if I strip my document of everything, and do a normal beamer or article class, it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}

\ex
\begingl[everyglpreamble=\it, belowglpreambleskip=0pt, aboveglftskip=0pt]
\gla batis-ne //
\glb feet-\sc{3.sg.poss}//
\glft`his/her feet'//
\endgl
\xe

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

According to the documentation, one can also use the command in the `\glft` line which I tried. It didn't work as well... Am I doing something wrong? I want to get rid of the vertical spacing above the glft line! I am also using the `expex` package in a paper I am writing and it's working fine there.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add your code in form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, and not images.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please don't just post screenshot of the code; otherwise people have to type it themselves to help you. You can edit your question to improve it.

Comment: And anyway your code works fine for me. Do you have anything else in your document that can affect this behavior?

Comment: There is no need to add a thank you remark as accepting or upvoting answer do just that. Also adding your signature at the end is not necessary since you already have it in your post (lower right corner). Welcome again to TeX.SX.

Comment: I also find no problem with your sample document.  I wonder if perhaps you have an old version of `expex` around that is being used.  Also, you should not use two-letter font commands (see [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361) ) and also these commands do not take arguments. (See [Is there a difference between \textit and \itshape?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8053)).

Answer (score 5):

To my eye, `aboveglftskip=0pt` doesn't get rid of all of the extra vertical space between the glosses and translation, even with the latest version of `expex` (2014/03/10 v5.0b); see below. To take care of this, I usually use a negative value of `aboveglftskip` (and `belowglpreambleskip`, which has the same problem), but this seems to me to be just a hack.

[image]

Produced by this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}

\ex
\begingl[everygla=]
\glpreamble XXXXXXXX (default) //
\gla XXXXXXXX //
\glb XXXXXXXX //
\glft XXXXXXXX (default)//
\endgl
\xe

\ex
\begingl[everygla=, belowglpreambleskip=0pt, aboveglftskip=0pt]
\glpreamble XXXXXXXX (0pt) //
\gla XXXXXXXX //
\glb XXXXXXXX //
\glft XXXXXXXX (0pt) //
\endgl
\xe

\ex
\begingl[everygla=, belowglpreambleskip=-0.5ex, aboveglftskip=-0.5ex]
\glpreamble XXXXXXXX (-0.5ex) //
\gla XXXXXXXX //
\glb XXXXXXXX //
\glft XXXXXXXX (-0.5ex) //
\endgl
\xe 

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get better results with `-6pt` using FreeSerif (XeLaTeX) with `\parskip` set to `6pt`.  `0.5ex` seems to be not enough.  I believe it's adding an extra parskip, but I haven't tracked down exactly what it's doing yet.

Comment: FYI, I've filed an issue at the `expex` repository about this: https://github.com/frampton/ExPex/issues/8

Answer (score 2):

I filed an [issue about this](https://github.com/frampton/ExPex/issues/8) at the `expex` github repo, and the author reported a short-term work around.

**TLDR**: You can set `\parskip` to `0pt` in `Everyex` (as below) and set a few other values to `0pt`.

```
\lingset{Everyex={\parskip=0pt}}
```

The following MWE is a complete work-around:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}

\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\lingset{
    aboveglftskip=0pt,
    belowglpreambleskip=0pt,
    belowpreambleskip=0pt,
    extraglskip=0pt,
    Everyex={\parskip=0pt},
}

\begin{document}

\ex
\begingl[everygla={}]
\glpreamble XXXXXXXX //
\gla XXXXXXXX //
\glb XXXXXXXX //
\glft XXXXXXXX //
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

It seems to result in evenly spaced lines:

[image: evenly spaced lines]

Without `extraglskip=0pt`, it looks like this, with most extra space gone:

[image: most extra space gone]

If `Everyex={\parskip=0pt}` is additionally removed, the following is the result, with lots of extra space (due to the `12pt` `\parskip`):

[image: lots of extra space]