# Italicize and Underline Keywords in lstdefinestyle

Tags: listings, lstdefinestyle

The documentation shows the following:

`keywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries\underbar`

For my 3rd set of keywords I have tried:

`keywordstyle = [3]\textit\underbar`

However, this doesn't work and results in no styling. Using just `\textit` or `\underbar` does work so I must be misunderstanding how to combine these things.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Providing a Mwe will help illuminate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that using `\itshape` instead of `\textit` makes it work.

I found `\itshape` on [this cheat sheet](https://wch.github.io/latexsheet/latexsheet-0.png)

Comment: That is because `\itshape` is a switch whereas `\textit` needs an argument, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/is-there-a-difference-between-textit-and-itshape