# moderncv package does not recognize \it command

Tags: bibtex, moderncv, patching

The `moderncv` package does not recognize `\it` command. Sure we can use `\textit` instead. The problem is that BibTeX generated files may contain `\it` commands ...

So, edition of the `bbl` file is required to change all the `\it` commands into `\textit` command. The same is true for other commands of the same type: `\rm`, `\bf` and so on.

Is there a way to force BibTeX to use `\textit` instead of `\it` or to force `moderncv` to understand `\it`?

Comment: Use `\itshape`, not `\it`, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/is-there-a-difference-between-textit-and-itshape. And `\bfseries` instead of `\bf`, etc. see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc

Answer (score 3):

That’s not an issue with `\moderncv`; the commands have been obsolete since LaTeX2e.  Among other problems, `\bf` and `\it` [don’t nest or respect the font-selection scheme.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc)

The replacement in modern LaTeX is `\itshape`, and its semantics are probably what you really want.  If you insist on `\it` as an alias, there’s `\newcommand` (But that’s a bad idea because then old code will expect different behavior.).  If you must restore the original command, `\DeclareOldFontCommand`, but you would be shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 3):

If the `\it` is inserted by some bibtex style you can certainly adapt this: Save the bst under another name, then search for the \it and replace it e.g. `\itshape` or whatever is sensible.

Beside this you are quite allowed to define an undefined command in whatever way you see fit.

If the `\it` is used only for text, then `\newcommand\it{\normalfont\itshape}` or `\newcommand\it{\itshape}` is probably a sensible replacement, if it is used also in math then you could use

```
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
```

or

```
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\itshape}{\mathit}
```

The variants with `\normalfont` fake the old behaviour of `\it` better, without it it works like the modern \itshape and allows nesting with other font commands.