# when I insert \latintext everything gets messy

Tags: babel, languages, greek

I am a novice in Latex and I write in Greek language a report. In the report I want to write a couple of terms in english so I use the command \latintext{} but then after that command everything gets messy. What can I do? Thanks

EDIT

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}


\title{Διπλωματική Εργασία}
\author{Δημήτρης Στεργίου }
\date{Σεπτέμβριος 2021}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{}
\latintext{alexandrov}

Αυτό είναι το Πρώτο κεφάλαιο

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any chance you could show us the problematic effect in a small (compilable - or at least as compilable as possible) example document? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 I did not know the command `\latintext` and a short google search did not turn up anything useful. It is also relevant if you use `babel` or `polyglossia` for localisation and if you use pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile.

Comment: @moewe, I edited my question. The problem starts when I insert the \latintext {} ,

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a compilable example document in the sense of https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864. It is important that you tell us which `\documentclass` you are using and which *relevant* packages you load in your preamble.

Comment: @moewe, I hope now it helps. Thanks

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should load packages only once. The example has two `\usepackage{amsthm}`s. Delete the second one. `\usepackage{amssymb}` already loads `amsfonts`, so you can drop the `\usepackage{amsfonts}`. Also keep in mind that `hyperref` should generally be loaded last. So you probably want to move `\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}` to before you load `hyperref`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\latintext` is not a macro that takes an argument, it is a switch that changes everything that comes after it within the current group. It works like `\bfseries` and `\itshape` and not like `\textbf` and `\textit` (see [Is there a difference between \textit and \itshape?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8053/35864)).

Either use curly braces around `\latintext` or use the macro version `\textlatin`.

As a rule of thumb I'd use `\textlatin{<text>}` for a few words and `{\latintext <longer text>}` (note the different bracing!) for longer text that spans several paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\begin{document}
Αυτό είναι το Πρώτο κεφάλαιο

{\latintext
alexandrov

also works for new paragraphs
}

Αυτό είναι το Πρώτο κεφάλαιο

\textlatin{alexandrov,
but we can't start a new paragraph here}

Αυτό είναι το Πρώτο κεφάλαιο
\end{document}
```

[image: Αυτό είναι το Πρώτο κεφάλαιο alexandrov also works for new paragraphs Αυτό είναι το Πρώτο κεφάλαιο alexandrov, but we can’t start a new paragraph here Αυτό είναι το Πρώτο κεφάλαιο]

---

Note that `\latintext` and `\textlatin` just switch to a font encoding that works for Latin text. If you plan to write longer passages in English (or another language with Latin alphabet), it would be better to load that language as secondary document language and use the appropriate language switching commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}

\begin{document}
Αυτό είναι το Πρώτο κεφάλαιο

{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
alexandrov

also works for new paragraphs
\end{otherlanguage}}

Αυτό είναι το Πρώτο κεφάλαιο

\foreignlanguage{english}{alexandrov,
but we can't start a new paragraph here}

Αυτό είναι το Πρώτο κεφάλαιο
\end{document}
```