# How to properly shorten if condition?

Tags: macros, errors, conditionals, variable, substitution

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mybold}[2]{\ifnum #1=1 \textbf{#2} \else{#2} \fi}
\mybold{1}{This should be bold}

\mybold{0}{This should NOT be bold}
\end{document}
```

In this code, the command `mybold` accepts a number and text. If the number is `1` the text is emphasized and if not it doesn't. It works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mybold}[2]{\ifnum #1=1 \textbf\fi{#2}}
\mybold{1}{This should be bold}

\mybold{0}{This should NOT be bold}
\end{document}
```

I tried shortening the first code by putting `#2` behind the if condition. However, I get `too many }'s` error. How do I get the second code to work?

Answer (score 2):

Do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mybold}[2]{\ifnum #1=1 \expandafter\textbf\fi{#2}}
\mybold{1}{This should be bold}

\mybold{0}{This should NOT be bold}
\end{document}
```

Explanation: TeX `\if...` commands works a bit unintuitive way, so the `\textbf` will "see" the `\fi`.
Refer to [What do \@firstoftwo and \@secondoftwo do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21262/250119).

If you want to learn the details of TeX macro programming, resources are at [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668/250119). But normally writing "simpler" code is better.

Comment: More simple macro is: `\def\mybold#1{\ifnum #1=1 \expandafter\textbf\fi}`

Comment: @wipet Simpler here mean "can be understood without knowing the detail of TeX macro expansion" , but then I do link to resources if anyone want to read.

Answer (score 0):

Although [user202729's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/672289/38080) is more to the point of the programming problem, to solve the typographic problem you may want to simply use a font switch instead of the `\textbf` command:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mybold}[2]{{\ifnum #1=1 \bfseries\fi #2}}% NOTICE the difference in grouping!
\mybold{1}{This should be bold}

\mybold{0}{This should NOT be bold}
\end{document}
```

Notice however that the two approaches are not exactly the same; there can be a [difference if italic correction is needed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/is-there-a-difference-between-textit-and-itshape) on the switch.