# Newenvironment for poems

Tags: environments

I would like to create a new environment to do this:

```
\begin{alltt}\normalfont
    \textit{#1}
\end{alltt}
```

where I would like to put some text instead of `#1`.
Text consists of  lines, as a poem:

aaa

bbb

ccc

I create the new environment like this:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{alltt}

\newenvironment{poem}[1]

{\begin{alltt}\normalfont 
        \textit{#1}}
    { \end{alltt} }
    
\begin{document}
        
    \begin{poem}
        {aaa
         bbb
         ccc}
    \end{poem}  
    
\end{document}
```

As result, the poem environment prints all the text in one line aaabbbccc.
How to make the new environment, so the lines are separated?

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.  If I guess enough code to try your environment, I get the text spread over 3 lines, not one.

Comment: \documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{alltt}

\newenvironment{poem}[1]
{\begin{alltt}\normalfont 
  \textit{#1}}
 { \end{alltt} }
 
\begin{document}
  
 \begin{poem}
  {aaa
   bbb
   ccc}
 \end{poem} 
 
\end{document}

Comment: I do not know how to show you real latex text with all the lines separately

Comment: Remove the `{....}` around your `aaa bbb ccc`

Comment: If I remove parentheses, the lines are separate, but only the first letter is in italic. I need everything in italic and in separate lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following definition without argument. The `\itshape` will switch the font to italic

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{alltt}

\newenvironment{poem}{%
  \begin{alltt}%
    \normalfont
    \itshape
}{%
  \end{alltt}%
}
    
\begin{document}
        
\begin{poem}
aaa
bbb
ccc
\end{poem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Could you, please, explain: why do not I need a parameter here?

Comment: \textit does not work. Is it difficult to explain, why?

Comment: @Marina You want the `aaa bbb ccc` in the body of the of the environment, not in an additional argument.

Comment: @Marina `\textit{...}` needs an argument, `\itshape` is a switch which will change all the font within the group.

Comment: Could you, please, give me a link, where I can read about it? Thanks.

Comment: @Marina See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8054/36296